# Hibernate + Postgres: simple query with bad performance

Tags: performance, hibernate, postgresql

In my JavaEE webapplication, I am querying a postgres database to get the data of an employees holidays.
The table `holiday` has the following columns:

- **id** bigint NOT NULL
- **start** timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
- **end** timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
- **employee_id** bigint (FK referencing PK of table `employee`, indexed)
- some other columns that do not seem to be related to my issue. Not much data in here.

**Goal**: Find any holiday entry of a specific employee concerning a given time interval (not necessarily completely, i.e. a holiday from 2009-12-30 to 2010-01-05 is a valid result when searching for holidays from 2010-01-01 to 2010-01-31).

That said, my named Query is:

```
SELECT 
    h 
FROM 
    Holiday h 
WHERE 
    h.employee.id = :employeeIdParam
AND (
        h.end BETWEEN :fromParam AND :toParam
    OR 
        h.start BETWEEN :fromParam AND :toParam
    )
```

Query execution using hibernate takes ~400ms, resulting in 100 selected rows out of only 2000 rows in total. Much too long, isn't it?
(Using pgAdmin, it takes ~12ms.)

What's the issue here?
*(Running on local machine - it's not a connection problem)*

*Using Wildfly 9.0, Postgres 9.4, Hibernate 4.3.1.*

**Update**

Database Log:

```
select holiday0_.id as id1_70_, holiday0_.end as end3_70_, holiday0_.employee_id as emplo10_70_, holiday0_.start as star6_70_
from holiday holiday0_ where holiday0_.employee_id=$1 and (holiday0_.end between $2 and $3 or holiday0_.start between $4 and $5)",
"Parameter: $1 = '2757', $2 = '2003-07-01 00:00:00', $3 = '2015-08-11 23:59:59', $4 = '2003-07-01 00:00:00', $5 = '2015-08-11 23:59:59'"
```

Comment: I would check 1) which queries are actually being sent to the database; 2) how long the execution of those queries takes; 3) how much time is spent mapping the query results to objects.

Comment: even 12 ms is too much (it seems to contain some network and pgadmin overhead). do you have all indexes? i would recommend a combined index here. and yes, check, which queries really end up on the server. those ORMs tend to do strange things.

Comment: I've added postgres' log showing the query - seems ok to me. Next query (which is unrelated to this one) is being executed 20ms later. May I assume that ~380ms are spent on mapping the result to pojo's? If not, how would I measure the plain execution time?